# How to list objects in a class

Tags: python, list, class, object

I have a class

```
class movie:

 def __init__(self, title, year, release):
    self._title = title
    self._year = year
    self._release= release

 def getTitle(self):
    return self._title
 def getYear(self):
    return self._year
 def getRel(self):
    return self._release

 def setTitle(self, title):
    self._title = movie
 def setYear(self, year):
    self._year = movie
 def setRel(self, release):
    self._release = movie


 def __str__(self):
    outputString = "Title:" + str(self._title) + "Year:" + str(self._year) + "Production:" + str(self._release)
    return outputString
```

and I want to create a list out of this

```
import movie

mfirst = movie.movie("The Shawshank Redemption", "1994", "Castle Rock Entertainment")
msecond = movie.movie("The Godfather", "1972", "Paramount Pictures")
```

is there a way where I can list titles, year, and production studio separately? 
I have tried different methods but keep receiving something like this `[<movie.movie instance at 0x10117ecf8>]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have setters and getters for getting the values so we can take advantage of that and for every object you instantiate you can apply a uniform query across all your objects.

In your movie.py

```
class Movie:

 def __init__(self, title, year, release):
    self._title = title
    self._year = year
    self._release= release

 def getTitle(self):
    return self._title
 def getYear(self):
    return self._year
 def getRel(self):
    return self._release

 def setTitle(self, title):
    self._title = movie
 def setYear(self, year):
    self._year = movie
 def setRel(self, release):
    self._release = movie


 def __str__(self):
    outputString = "Title:" + str(self._title) + "Year:" + str(self._year) + "Production:" + str(self._release)
    return outputString
```

In another file let's call it my_movies.py

```
from movie import Movie

first_movie = Movie("The Shawshank Redemption", "1994", "Castle Rock Entertainment")

second_movie = Movie("The Godfather", "1972", "Paramount Pictures")

my_movies = [first_movie, second_movie]

titles = []
years = []
releases = []

for m in my_movies:
    titles.append(m.getTitle())
    years.append(m.getYear())
    releases.append(m.getRel())

print('\t'.join(titles))
print('\t'.join(years))
print('\t'.join(releases))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This has helped understand classes, setters, and getters much better and clarified a lot of things to me. May I ask what the `\t` is for?

Comment: It separates all the items of your list with tabs. Glad it was helpful please close the question by picking my answer ;)